# Camry 01 loosing coolant

Tags: toyota, cooling-system, camry

I've camry 2001 LE, with 149K on it.
Recently, I noticed coolant leak from the radiator and replaced the radiator.
I still was loosing coolant little bit, so performed coolant pressure test. The upper radiator hose was leaking, so replaced that.

I'm still losing small amount of coolant in the reservoir. I again did the coolant pressure test today, but didn't detect any leak. But the pressure on the gauge dropped very, very slowly.

What would be next best thing to do/replace?
Thanks!

Comment: Btw, what causes crack in the head gasket?

Comment: You should put that as another question.

Comment: It stopped leaking after 2 weeks or so. Now running fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would see what happens over a weeks time. You may have air trapped in the system that is slowly working it's way out. If it continues I would start with the following. Remove the spark plugs and put the pressure tester on. If you think the tester will hold pressure for a while let it sit pressurized, you can leave it overnight. Check and see if you see coolant leaking out of the sparkplug holes. If you see coolant, it an indicator of head gasket failure. With 149,000 you have to decide what to do if you have a leak. I have had success with the chemical additive products for small leaks like yours.

Comment: If you DO see coolant leaking out the spark plug holes, DO NOT put the spark plugs back in until you've turned the engine over at least twice! If you do, you run the risk of hydrostatic lock and serious internal damage. Which... probably would have happened already, if it COULD happen.